# How to build a mySQL function to access K2 extra_fields

Tags: php, mysql, json, function, joomla-k2

I need a function which will accept 4 parameters, in order to do some calculations using K2 `extra_fields`, and return the result into a `SELECT` statement.

I need the function to calculate the distance between 2 points. The coordinates of the first point will be found in the item's `extra_fields`. The coordinates of the second point will be given manually, in a php script.

My `extra_fields` contain:

```
[{"id":"1","value":"40.111"},{"id":"2","value":"20.222"}]
```

where id[1] and id[2] are coordinates (latitude and longitude).

The SELECT statement should look like:

```
SELECT id, title, **FUNCTION_GOES_HERE** AS 'distance'
FROM k2_items;
```

I am not looking for the distance calculation algorithm. The problem is how to extract the coordinates from the `extra_fields` field.
Any ideas?

Comment: What about using the PHP function [json_decode](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)?

Comment: i tried that, but i want to receive the distance direct from the database, so i can later filter rows that i do not need.

Comment: It's not a good idea to store data in json format in MySQL because MySQL currently doesn't have any json support I'm aware of. So you better store them in two individual fields, say `lat` and `long`. If you can't change your design, it would be best to write a stored function that extract those values from this special json string.

Comment: Since i am using Joomla extension K2, i cannot do much with the database structure. And the question is still, how to build such a function?

Answer (score 0):

Because you can't change your table design, you've got to do a bit of tedious string parsing. Here an example:

```
SELECT 
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(extra_fields, '"value":"', -2), '"', 1) as latitude,
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(extra_fields, '"value":"', -1), '"', 1) as longitude
FROM k2_items;
```

**[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0bd39b/1)**

**Explanation:**

We find the substring "value":" two times in those values:

```
[{"id":"1","value":"40.111"},{"id":"2","value":"20.222"}]
           ^ first time                ^ second time

SUBSTRING_INDEX(extra_fields, '"value":"', -2
```

will give us with the sample data the substring beginning after the second last occurence of our needle, here the first occurence:

```
40.111"},{"id":"2","value":"20.222"}]
```

For the latitude we need the substring until the next double quote. That's a simple one: `SUBSTRING_INDEX(haystack, needle, 1)` with our first expression as haystack and the double quote as needle.

```
SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(extra_fields, '"value":"', -2), '"', 1)
```

gives us the desired result:

```
40.111
```

By the same logic we'll get the longitude.